# call a JS function in Angular CLI

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to call a JS function (API call) in Angular . I first tried it in HTML/JS where everything worked, but now in Angular it doesn't.

In my app.component.html I made a button, which should call a function in the ts file.

```
<button (click)="CallFBNewsFeed()">Login with Facebook</button>
```

In my app.component.ts I got the function, which should be called.
First:

```
declare var getFBNewsfeed: any;
```

Then in the export class AppComponent:

```
CallFBNewsFeed() {
    console.log("CallNewsFeed")
    getFBNewsfeed.func1();
}
```

And in my script.js, which I imported in my ts file, this code should do:

```
var getFBNewsfeed = (function() {

    return {
        func1: function() {
            function getNewsFeed() {

                FB.api("/ORF/feed", { access_token: 'xxx' }, 
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                        if (response && !response.error) {
                            console.log("Hi")
                            /* handle the result */
                        }
                });
            }
        },

    }

})(getFBNewsfeed||{})
```

When I run my project and click the button, I get this error:

ERROR ReferenceError: getFBNewsfeed is not defined  Stack trace: [...]

What am I doing wrong and how can I get this to work? Thank you

Comment: If its angular 2 +, isnt onclick syntax is <button (click)="CallFBNewsFeed()"></button> ? or for other angular version it is <button ng-click="CallFBNewsFeed()"></button>

Comment: I'm using Angular CLI: 1.7.1 and Angular: 4.4.6, i changed it to (click) now

Comment: So Is it working now ?

Comment: yes and no, now it can find CallFBNewsFeed, but I get ReferenceError: getFBNewsfeed is not defined
because my trying in script.js doesn't work

Comment: did you refer your  script.js in required components page?

Comment: In my app.component.ts I imported it - import './script'
Is something missing?

Comment: I hope so.. Didnt completely remember how we import scripts in angular2+

Comment: by chance Did that work?

Comment: now it can find CallFBNewsFeed, but I get ReferenceError: getFBNewsfeed is not defined because my script.js doesn't work

Comment: even after importing it in your component?

Comment: I am not sure of this syntax.. var getFBNewsfeed = ........  :(

Comment: How would you do change it? :(

Comment: Please add a working snippet which gives you error so that we can check it

Comment: I "solved" the problem now by keeping the working code in the html and using an iframe in angular

Comment: It would be better if you post it as an answer so that if some one has similar issue, they can benefit out of it

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be added in controller scope.

Your function should be in controller like

```
$scope.CallFBNewsFeed = function() {
    console.log("CallNewsFeed")
    getFBNewsfeed.func1();
  }
```

and you should use `ng-click`  event instead of `onclick`

> And please take a look at this [document](https://www.sitepoint.com/api-calls-angularjs-http-service/) for how to  call api and bind the result in html by using angularjs

Comment: If I use this code in my ts file, it's getting an error (; expected)
And I tried looking at this document, but it doesn't seem to function (demo, git repo) and I'm using angular cli, not adding angular as a script

Comment: Then you are not using `angularjs` :) . Please take a look at the document which is am mentined in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, i edited it :)
Yes i did, but it doesn't seem to function

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 2+,
Use `<button (click)="CallFBNewsFeed()">Login with Facebook</button>`

and for Angular 1.x
Use `<button ng-click="CallFBNewsFeed()">Login with Facebook</button>`

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" the problem now by keeping the code in the html (where everything works) and using an iframe in angular to display everything.